Netlogo-headless.sh error when running on HPC
Half of my jobs I submit to my HPC return the following error message in the out file and ends my Job:
/sw/rl8/zen/app/NetLogo/6.4.0-64/netlogo-headless.sh: line 34: 111089 Killed "$JAVA" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$ABSOLUTE_CLASSPATH" org.nlogo.headless.Main "${ARGS[@]}"

Anyone any idea what is wrong? Below my Slurm script:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32
#SBATCH --partition= univ.default.q
#SBATCH --job-name=temst
#SBATCH --time=2:00:00
#SBATCH --output=%j.out
#SBATCH --array=1-50
module load NetLogo/6.4.0-64

cd $HOME/

mdl="temst.nlogo"
xpt="experiment1DR"
out=${xpt}.out
tab=${xpt}-${SLURM_JOBID}-${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.csv

netlogo-headless.sh --model $mdl --threads 32 --experiment $xpt --table $tab

I tried, limiting threads, not using --array but all eventually return the same error.

the error that you're seeing means that the process is being terminated by the system. There could be several reasons, one of them is memory limit exceeded, #SBATCH --mem=16G add memory allocation, also try to reduce the threads: #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
